# Saving file data in an SQL Server database through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a problem in saving file data and retrieving content in original form using SQL Server.

To save content, I have used this code

```
$size = filesize($file);
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
$content = fread($fp, $size);
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

and database to store its content is of type image.

Comment: What problem do you have? Maybe that `addslashes()` adds slashes?

Comment: Why in the world would you ever, *ever* `addslashes` to anything?  `addslashes` is a code smell.  Also, what does writing a file to disk have to do with storing anything in SQL Server?

Comment: Can we see the code that reads and writes to MSSQL? The code you've supplied doesn't do anything with a database at all.

Comment: @Charles He might want to read the file from disk and upload the image to the database .

Comment: yeah, bit then he has a mental disconnect. Question and code have no correlation, no explanation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Never do **addslashes** to binary files.**addslashes** should only be done on text data.

*Image files,audio video files and executable all are binary files.*

Try removing `addslashes` and try again.If it still doesn't get inserted into your database then you should check if the datatype of the column in your database is set to **`blob`**.Only **blob** datatype can hold binary data.

If still you have problems inserting to database then try inserting smaller images of size smaller than 1mb. php has  a default *post* and *file upload* limit of 2mb.